# creating an SDL2 window inside GHCI

Tags: haskell, sdl-2, ghci

I have been using [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2) SDL2 bindings. Although I can execute my compiled program, I cannot open a window from GHCi, no matter what I try. I've tried out the examples from the repository, but they have the same issue. The error message I keep getting is:

```
*** Exception: SDLCallFailed {sdlExceptionCaller = "SDL.Video.getWindowSurface", sdlFunction = "SDL_GetWindowSurface", sdlExceptionError = "Invalid window"}
```

If it's of any relevance I'm on macOS. I'm also not necessarily married to this library, and if there is a way to create a window from GHCi with a different library, I'd be interested.

Comment: Are you using Nix? https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/issues/196

Comment: I worked with sdl haskell bindings long ago. I do remember that ghci didn't get along with them easily. I also remember something about the `-threaded` option

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm using stack no nix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using stack, and this fixed my issues:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options '-fno-ghci-sandbox'
```

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but I have a hunch it has something to do with ghci spawning threads, and SDL2 wanting the window in the main thread. If anyone has a better understanding of these things I'm very interested.

Comment: Great tip. Have you found a way to destroy the window when the application exits, without having to quit GHCI ? I thought destroyWindow would do it, but am having no success.